# Computing Fourier Transform of Triangle Function

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

I am trying to compute the Fourier transform  of the triangle function
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 -| x |  & \text{if}~~ | x |\leq 1 \\
0 & \text{if}~~ | x | > 1 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

using the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f$(x)e$^{-ikx}$dx. Plugging in the equation I get $\hat{f}$ =$\int_{-1}^{1} (1 - | x |)$ e$^{-ikx}$ dx which I expand to to $\hat{f}$ =$\int_{-1}^{0} e^{-ikx} + xe^{-ikx}$ dx +  $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-ikx} - xe^{-ikx}$ dx. Evaluating the integrals then adding gives me $\frac{2}{k^2}$ - $\frac{2e^{-ik}(1-ik)}{k^2}$.

However, the result is apparently supposed to be $\frac{\sin^4y}{y^4}$, which I don't see how I can get to from what I have. Is there some different way to proceed to get this result?

Comment: Let $g(x) = 1$ for $x \in [-1/2,1/2]$ and $0$ otherwise. Note that $f$ is the convolution of $g$ with itself. Then using the properties of Fourier Transform, the Fourier Transform of $f$ is the square of that of $g$.

Comment: Do you mean $0$ if $|x| > 1$?

Comment: Carrying out the integral $\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} g(x) e^{-ikx}$dx gives me $\frac{2sin(\frac{k}{2})}{k}$ which squares to give $\frac{4sin^2(\frac{k}{2})}{k^2}$. So is the given solution of the form $\frac{sin^4k}{k^4}$ just wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned} 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-iyx} \, dx &= \int_{-1}^0 (1+x) e^{-iyx} \, dx + \int_0^1 (1-x) e^{-iyx} \, dx\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{y^2} - \frac{e^{iy}}{y^2} + \frac{i}{y} \right]+\left[\frac{1}{y^2} - \frac{e^{-iy}}{y^2} - \frac{i}{y} \right] \\&= \frac{2-2 \cos y}{y^2}.
\end{aligned} $$

Using the trigonometric identity $$1 -\cos y  = 2 \sin^2\frac{y}{2}$$ we can write the integral as

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-iyx} \, dx = \frac{4 \sin^2\frac{y}{2}}{y^2}$$ which will be found following the suggestion in the comments to use convolution.

Comment: Thank you for the edits!